# docker pull registry.access.redhat.com throws error HTTP 403

Tags: docker, dockerfile, redhat, redhat-containers

When I try to pull docker image from registry.access.redhat.com it throws an error. Does anyone encounter this issue?
     docker -D pull registry.access.redhat.com/rhel7:7.2-104

```
Error response from daemon: error parsing HTTP 403 response body: invalid character '<' looking for beginning of value: "<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC \"-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01//EN\" \"http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/strict.dtd\">\n<html>\n<head>\n<meta http-equiv=\"Content-Type\" content=\"text/html; charset=iso-8859-1\">\n<title>Certificate verification error</title>\n<link rel=\"stylesheet\" href=\"https://registry.access.redhat.com/%24%24%24%26%3f%26%3f%24%24%24?cmd=get_file&arg=block_style.css&sid=ED86B21DBBB596DD1E11988BA78DC7243705B90A\" type=\"text/css\">\n</head>\n<body>\n\n<div id=\"pagecontainer\">\n        <img class=\"icon\" src=\"https://registry.access.redhat.com/%24%24%24%26%3f%26%3f%24%24%24?cmd=get_file&arg=images/block.png&sid=DC867D9D2DB12A688F1AC8747503340D380393F8\"> <!--Icon for block type-->\n        <h1>Certificate verification error</h1>\n\n        <div class=\"row\">\n                <p class=\"label\">Overview:</p>\n                <p class=\"item\">Access denied. Certificate validation failed for the following URL: registry.access.redhat.com </p>\n        </div>\n        <div class=\"row\">\n                <p class=\"label\">Details:</p>\n                <p class=\"item\">Client Certificate requested: registry.access.redhat.com</p>\n        </div>\n\n        <div id=\"options\">\n                <p class=\"label\">Options:</p>\n                                \n                <form action=\"\"><input type=\"button\" class=\"button\" onclick=\"history.back();\" value=\"   Go Back   \"></form><p class=\"item\">Click to return to the previous page:</p>\n                                <p class=\"last-item\">To find out more about why access was denied, please contact your administrator. The reference ID is 0.</p>\n        </div>\n\n        <div><img class=\"logo\" title=\"Forcepoint\" src=\"https://registry.access.redhat.com/%24%24%24%26%3f%26%3f%24%24%24?cmd=get_file&arg=images/wslogo_block_page.png&sid=C76C948261ED7888B0BBD6EBE1CB637E7690A00E\" alt=\"Forcepoint Logo\">\n                <div style=\"clear: both; overflow: hidden; height:1px;\"></div>\n        </div>\n</div>\n\n</body>\n</html>"
```

Answer (score 1):

@sothish as per "Certificate verification error" looks like you are using a docker daemon which does have valid cert for `registry.access.redhat.com` you might to add this as insecure registry and try again.